# $\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)g(x)h(x)dx$ equality

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ be functions integrable on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Does $\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)g(x)h(x)dx=f(x)g(x)h(x)|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g'(x)h(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)h'(x)dx$? This question with the numerous derivatives of functions seems to apply the Leibniz Formula for derivatives of an integral, though I know it is not since we're not finding the derivative here. I also notice a patter of each equation only having one function that is a derivative, for example, $f'(x), g'(x), h'(x)$. The real problem is I don't have a method of checking whether this equation holds true or not, since the functions are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g'(x)h(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)h'(x)dx  = 
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)(g(x)h(x))'dx
$$

Comment: Just a quick followup: are there alternative ways to prove the statement above?

Comment: I just want a quick answer, no need to derive a new proof for me :D